# How to set the expiration date for a FB Channel File in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I am creating the channelfile for FB

```
cache_expire = 60*60*24*365
response.headers["Pragma"] = "public"
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=#{cache_expire}"
response.headers["Expires"] = ... # gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
```

How do I set the "Expires" value in Rails 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 response.headers["Expires"] = Time.at(Time.now.to_i + cache_expire).strftime("%D, %d %M % Y %H:%i:%s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a gem to that automatically mounts an engine at /channel.html. You can simply include 'fb-channel-file' in your Gemfile More info in my answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10643780/105293)